# Azure monitoring says that my West US instance is unavailable in some regions

Tags: web-hosting, azure

I have a website hosted in Azure. 
Today I started getting alerts that site is down in 3 locations. 
Availability report is showing Central, South Central, and West US as down. 
[image: Azure Portal Availability Report]

On [azure status](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/) there are no outages.

Am I doing something wrong here? My website is configured as West US, I have not configured any multi-region redundancy as far as I can remember.

Comment: What monitoring service are you using?  It could be an issue with the monitoring service rather than with the hosting service.

Comment: This is azure monitoring, not a third party. The image is from azure portal. According to them 3 regions are down...